# AWS ECS ALB Error (Request timed out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to learn/use AWS ECS but keep getting

> service  has reached a steady state.

Followed by:

> service  (instance i-05873e2a55ecba2f6) (port 32768) is unhealthy in target-group  due to (reason Request timed out)

I'm not really sure which info you need to help, but I was using this load balancer across EC2 instances before, but I am replacing those EC2 instances with ones launched through ECS and now I am running into this error.

My cluster is in my default VPC and I am including all 3 subnets (East zone). The security group is my load balancer security group which allows all traffic on ports 40 and 443. I have tried changing security group so that it allows anyone on any port but that doesn't work.

My host port in my task definition is 0 and my container port is 3000 which is what I exposed in Dockerfile.

The healthcheck is just on the target port at path "/"

Comment: what is instance security group? is the port 32768 open at instance level?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that

Comment: are you able to connect to app from the host container? `curl <ip>:3000`

Comment: can you confirm if the healthcheck port is `32768` or the one on which the service is running ?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran If I SSH into the EC2 instance and then try to curl <ip>:3000, I get a connection timed out

Comment: @kintuparantu I don't think it is a healthcheck issue, but the healthcheck is checking on the traffic port (which should be the assigned port)

Comment: So, you need to fix the timeout problem first and make <ip>:3000 work

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran The timeout is fixed but now I am running into a healthcheck error "Health checks failed with these codes: [302]"

Comment: 302 is for url redirecting, pls see my answer for fixing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389510/aws-elb-health-check-failing-at-302-code

Answer (score 5):

Remember to check the outbound rule of your ALB security group. Target group health check actually issues the request from ALB. So if your ALB is not allowed to talk to your target, it will also fail.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to lose the plot on this one.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059851/aws-ecs-service-tasks-getting-replaced-with-reason-request-timed-out/58060047#58060047) summarize a checklist of points to verify when debugging this kind of error:

- be the case, there is no route `Path  /healthcheck` in the backend
  service
- The status code from `/healthcheck` is not `200`
- Might be the case that target port is invalid, configure it correctly, if an
  application running on port 8080 or 3000 it should be `3000` or `8080`
- The security group is not allowing traffic on the target group
- Application is not running in the container

Comment: If you are using Terraform to deploy some restricted SG, don't forget to add the `self` attribute so the port will be allowed on your own SG (which will be the one used for ELB taget) : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#self

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the same. Check the inbound rule of the security group of the ALB, there should be something like this.
`All traffic /  All /   All /   "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx"   –`.

`sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx` this should be the security group of your application load balancer.